# No me deja conectar a SQL cloud google

Tags: sql, cloud

Estoy intentando conectarme desde Mysql Workbench a una instancia de sql cloud google, y no me deja, me pone este error, donde he puesto la ip de la direccion ip publica, lo que quiero es conectarme al workbench para poder usar sentencias sql

[image: error reported]

Cual es la passwrd por defecto de sql cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

necesitas crear una instancia Cloud SQL y ahí configurar tu usuario, te comparto el link para más explicación: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/create-manage-users

Comment: Bien, me faltaba por crear un usuario para no conectarme con root, y autorizar mi ip para conectarme a la bbdd